# Extend inequality for $L^2$-inner product

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space and $f\in L^2(\mu)$. Assume there is a $c\ge0$ with that we know that $$|\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}|\le c\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\tag1$$ for all $g\in L^2(\mu)$ with $g\ge0$ and $\int g\:{\rm d}\mu=1$.

> Are we able to extend to all $g\in L^2(\mu)$ with $\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\le1$?

My idea was to consider the positive $g^+$ and negative part $g^-$ of $g$, i.e. $g^\pm=\max(0,\pm g)$, but I end up with $|\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}|\le c\left(\left\|g^+\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}+\left\|g^-\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\right)$, which is not enough.

Comment: For any $g\in L^2$ (for now assume $||g||\neq 0$), take $g/||g||$. If $||g|| = 0$ then the inequality is obvious. Conclusion, the inequality holds for all $g$. In reality, we are saying that $g\mapsto (f|g)$ is a continuous operator. For $c$ we can take the norm of that operator. In fact, since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, the operator is indeed always continuous. The space being probability space doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you need to extend with the same constant? because the work you've done proves the extension if you can replace $c$ with $2c$ since $\|g^+\|, \|g^-\| \leq \|g\|$.

Comment: @Jakobian I imagine the real difficulty OP is having is removing the assumption on the sign of $g$, rather than normalisation. As far as I can tell, your comment only deals with the normalisation.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, the constant needs to be the same. (BTW, this is an attempt to solve this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3288913/47771. At least under the reversibility assumption.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. In fact, I will prove the stronger statement that it cannot be done even if you strengthened your first assumption to hold for all $g \in L^2(\mu)$ with $g \geq 0$.

In this case, essentially you would be asking if 
$$\|f\|_{L^2(\mu)} = \sup_{g \in B} |\langle f,g \rangle| = \sup_{g \in B^+} |\langle f,g \rangle |$$
for an arbitrary $f$, where $B$ is the unit ball of $L^2(\mu)$ and $B^+$ is the set of non-negative elements of $B$.

Consider the case where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and let $f = 1_{[0,1/2)} - 1_{[1/2,1]}$. Then $\|f\|_{L^2(\mu)} = 1$ and so we would want to have that $\sup_{g \in B^+} |\langle f,g \rangle| = 1$.

Clearly that $\sup$ is the same as the supremum over the set of $g \in B^+$ such that $g = 0$ on $[1/2,1]$. Let $B_0^+$ be the set of $g \in B^+$ such that $g = 0$ on $[1/2,1]$. Then, by Holder's inequality, we have that
$$\sup_{g \in B_0^+} |\langle f, g \rangle| = \sup_{g \in B_0^+} \int_0^{\frac12} g d\mu \leq \sup_{g \in B_0^+} \|g\|_{L^2(\mu)} \cdot \mu([0,1/2))^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2^{-\frac12} < 1.$$

Hence the two suprema are not equal.

Comment: Then I've no idea how we can prove the claim in the other question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3288913/47771) which is "proved" here https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/Markov_Processes_1617/MPSkript1617.pdf in Corollary 7.4 or I'm missing something crucial.