# Equivalence between the "supremum formula" and the "maximum formula" of the "total variation distance"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, total-variation

**Introduction.** In a previous post, [Definitions of the total variation distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767924/definitions-of-the-total-variation-distance/4767947?noredirect=1#comment10129987_4767947), I asked about the equivalences among different definitions of the "total variation distance" $d_{TV}$:

> I found the following definitions of the total variation distance
> $d_{TV}$ between two probability distributions (also called
> probability measures) $P$ and $Q$ on $\mathcal{A}$ (please note that I
> tried to use a consistent notation in the following definitions!):
>
> \begin{align} &{\color{red}{\textbf{Definition 1.}}}\quad{\color{blue}{\textbf{"Definition 2.4" on page 84, in
> > Tsybakov (2009)}}} \\&\hspace{10ex} d_{TV}(P,Q)
> > = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left| P(A)-Q(A) \right| = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left| \int_{A} (p-q)d\nu \,\right| \\ \\
>  &{\color{red}{\textbf{Definition 2.}}}\quad{\color{blue}{\textbf{"2.1 Definition" on page 5, in Strasser
> > (1985)}}} \\&\hspace{10ex}d_{TV}(P,Q)
> > = \left\Vert P-Q\right\Vert = \sup \{\left| P(A)-Q(A) \right| : {A \in \mathcal{A}} \} \\ \\ &{\color{red}{\textbf{Definition 3.}}}\quad{\color{blue}{\textbf{"4.1. Total Variation
> > Distance" on page 47, in Levin&Peres (2017)}}}
>  \\&\hspace{10ex}d_{TV}(P,Q)
> > = \left\Vert P-Q\right\Vert = \max_{A \subseteq \mathcal{A}} \left| P(A)-Q(A) \right| \\ \\ &{\color{red}{\textbf{Definition 4.}}}\quad{\color{blue}{\textbf{On page 22, in Villani
> > (2008)}}}\\&\hspace{10ex}d_{TV}(P,Q)
> > = \left\Vert P-Q\right\Vert = 2 \inf \left\{ \mathbb{E} [\mathcal{1}_{X \neq Y}]; \,\text{law}(X)=P, \text{law}(Y)=Q \right\}
>  \\ \end{align}

I received very nice replies and things are getting clearer. However, I am not able to figure out how to show what suggested by @John Dawkins in his answer, i.e. to show that Definition 2 and Definition 3 are equivalent, by using the densities of $P$ and $Q$:

> One can take the measure $\nu$ in the first definition to be $P+Q$.
> Then $P\ll\nu$ so (Radon-Nikdym) there is a density $p$ such that
> $P(A)=\int_Ap\,d\nu$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$. Likewise, there's a
> density $q$ such that $Q(A)=\int_A q\,d\nu$.
>
> There is another (equivalent) definition based on  these densities:
> $\|P-Q\|={1\over 2}\int|p-q|\,d\nu$.
>
> Using this you can show that the supremum in definition 2 is attained
> at $A=\{x: p(x) > q(x)\}$. This shows that definitions 2 and 3 are
> equivalent.

In [Definition of the total variation distance: $ V(P,Q) = \frac{1}{2} \int |p-q|d\nu$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481101/definition-of-the-total-variation-distance-vp-q-frac12-int-p-qd-n), I guess I found something very related to the suggestion of @John Dawkins, i.e. the proof of one equality among the densities of $P$ and $Q$ (by using both $B=\{p\geq q\}$ and $A$ sets):
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{A} \left| p-q \right|
= \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left| \int_{A} (p-q) d\nu \right|
\end{equation}
But still, a part is missing in showing that Definition 2 and Definition 3 of my post are equivalent, i.e. the following (I guess):
\begin{equation}
\sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left| \int_{A} (p-q) d\nu \right|
= \max_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left| \int_{A} (p-q) d\nu \right|
\end{equation}

**Question.** Do you have any suggestion or reference about how to show that definitions 2 and 3 are equivalent, by using the suggestion/path proposed by @John Dawkins?

**Note.** I think, that, maybe,  an alternative way to show that definitions 2 and 3 are equivalent, could be to just say what kindly indicated by angryavian in his answer, still in my previous post ([Definitions of the total variation distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767924/definitions-of-the-total-variation-distance/4767947?noredirect=1#comment10129987_4767947)), i.e.:

> - If $\Omega$ is finite, then any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is finite, since the power set is finite.
> - If $\mathcal{A}$ is finite, then $\max_{A \in \mathcal{A}}$ exists and is equivalent to $\sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}$.

However, it would be very interesting to explore the path proposed by @John Dawkins, as well!