# Simple equality of total variation distance

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand the following equality involving probability measures in Wikipedia:

$$\|\mu-\nu\|=|\mu-\nu|(X)=2 \sup \{|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|: A \in \Sigma\}$$

where the total variation norm $\|\cdot\|$ and the total variation of a measure $|\cdot|$ are defined in the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_of_probability_measures). The article has been flagged for not citing sources or offering a proof.

I have found a proof of a similar result for discrete probability distributions (1). But I have not been able to adapt it to continuous probability distributions, which is the result above.

(1) Proposition 4.2 in Markov Chains and Mixing Times, 2017

Comment: you can adapt it by using integrals, no?

Comment: Not quite. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

First we need to show $\mu-\nu(\cdot)$ is a (finite) signed measure. I am not sure if that is trivial or requires some clever trick. Then, we let $B$ be the measurable set $E\cap D^+$ using the Hahn decomposition ($D^+\sqcup D^-$) of $X$ under $\mu-\nu$ s.t. $\mu-\nu$ is positive on $D^+$. It is then easy to prove that for all $A \in \Sigma$, $\mu(A)-\nu(A) \le \mu(B)-\nu(B)$ and $\nu(B)-\mu(A)$ $\le \nu(B^c)-\mu(B^c) = \mu(B)-\nu(B) $. Then you go on to say that

$$\sup_{A\in\Sigma} |\mu(A)-\nu(A)| \le \mu(B)-\nu(B)$$

and, since $B\in\Sigma$,

$$\sup_{A\in\Sigma} |\mu(A)-\nu(A)| \ge \mu(B)-\nu(B).$$

From this, it is possible to conclude

$$\begin{aligned}\sup_{A\in\Sigma} |\mu(A)-\nu(A)| &= \mu(B)-\nu(B) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\mu(B)-\nu(B) + \nu(B^c)-\mu(B^c) ) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\mu(A\cup D^+)-\nu(A\cup D^+) + \nu(A\cup D^-)-\mu(A\cup D^-) ) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}( (\mu-\nu)(A\cup D^+) + (\mu-\nu)(A\cup D^-) ) \\
&=|\mu-\nu|(A).\end{aligned}$$